# Possibility of calling remote methods via sockets in java?

Tags: java, sockets, socket.io, serversocket

Is it possible to call remote method and get return value of the method through sockets in java without rmi client/server implementation?

Comment: Are you sure you want to re-invent the wheel.  Maybe you don't want to use rmi, but there are other alternatives like HTTP REST SOAP etc.

Comment: Why? All you'll be doing is reimplementing RMI. It's already done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, if you design the protocol and infrastructure to marshal/unmarshal the call, arguments and return value.  Anything is possible, the only question is how much work you want to do reinventing existing wheels.

Comment: Thanks mate. Is there are any examples for this?

Comment: Here's a [link from Google](http://coopsoft.com/ar/rmi_article.html) you could have found yourself.